# MI BAND 2 disconnects after few seconds (Bluez)

Tags: bluez

I have a problem connecting to a MI BAND 2 watch, which can measure heart rate.

When i run bluetoothctl i do the following:

```
scan on
connect connect CD:1D:69:25:19:5E
Attempting to connect to CD:1D:69:25:19:5E
Connection successful
[MI Band 2]#
```

then after a few seconds, i get:

```
[CHG] Device CD:1D:69:25:19:5E ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device CD:1D:69:25:19:5E Connected: no
```

I have also tried to pair the device, but end up with the same result.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: This happens when the minimum expected profiles for the device is not met/present in Bluez. Share the complete logs while using pair/connect command. Also dbus-monitor output should help narrow down the real need of the device.

Comment: Also share the "show" command output from bluetoothctl CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. Somehow the MI BAND 2 needs to go through an authentication process.

I followed this guide:
https://leojrfs.github.io/writing/miband2-part1-auth/

I used the openssh to encrypt the key.